# Why is my camera stuck In the torso of my character?

Tags: rendering, camera

I began trying to position the camera by going into camera view.  The camera view was in the torso of my character for some reason.

I had a camera in the scene, but as far as I know the camera is not a child of the rig.  I also tried removing the camera and adding it again but that still didn't help.

Comment: Did you try moving the camera?

Comment: Is it possible your character object is set as the camera? Try adding a camera somewhere else and pressing `Ctrl+numpad 0` with it selected.

Comment: @iKlsR I did try moving the camera and that had no effect.

Comment: Could you upload the .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend/ ? I only know the effect that the viewport can't zoom any further which can be fixed by selecting another pivot point followed by Numpad-.

Comment: I uploaded the rig on that site.  I added a password to it which is "blendercamera"  Thanks for helping me so far.

Comment: Didn't put the link.  Here it is http://pasteall.org/blend/31121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no camera object in your scene, and the cube object is set as the scene camera (yes, you can have non-camera objects set as the camera):

[image]

Add a real [camera object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera) by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Camera* in *object mode*, then make it the active scene camera by setting it in *Properties editor > Scene > Scene > Camera*, or by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> with it selected:

[image]

This way you can move the camera object around as you like, and set camera options such as focal length, DoF, lens type, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you zoom you always zoom to distinct point which could be e.g. the object's center or a selected vertex. You can can't beyond the this point by zooming further.

The easiest way is to select another point and press <kbd>Numpad-.</kbd> (period)

To get away from the close-up is using the mouse wheel or <kbd>Home</kbd>

Illustration of how it works:

[image]
Resources

- [Noob to Pro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Navigation_in_3D#Zoom)
- [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that my object was selected to be a active câmera. To remove that, you need to go to: properties panel/ Scene and there you remove the object selected.

Comment: Isn't this the same information as gandalf3's answer from 5 years ago? How does this answer differ?

Answer (score -1):

click on the camera ( choose camera ) then click ctrl 0 ( 0 from numpad )